# Matlab: simulate command window input by a script

Tags: matlab, command, execute

I need a way to execute a script in matlab from within another script. The tricky part is, that the first script is a while loop, which polls every 60 seconds for a new job. If a job is found (created by me), the main.m file should be called. Now, the problem is that I want to be able to modify main.m and all other functions while the while loop is already running. The loop looks something like this:

```
while run
   - pause 60 seconds 
   - get jobs form text file on network drive
   - run main(jobID)
   - save result on network drive
end
```

I thought the eval command would do the trick. But it doesn't. I think Matlab compiles all functions that could be called during runtime as soon as I start my while loop. From then on I cant change anything without restarting the while loop. (I can change it but Matlab ignores all changes).

Is there a way around this problem? I thought there was a method of executing commands inside the command window, just as if a user had typed it. But I cant remember.

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints and executing your script with pressing F10 to go line by line?

Comment: That wouldn't be satisfying because I would like to have matlab "waiting" for me with this while loop and then pick a job, execute, save files and return to while loop. Reason for that is, that I want to use around 20 workstations, but I dont have any access to a real cluster. So I'm kind of putting the jobs in there and the first free computer which repeats the while loop takes on this job.

Comment: Can you add mex extension to your server? You could start another instance of Matlab with "popen" and work with its command window. Standard library doesn't have "popen", it is only available with the help of C extensions

Comment: @potAito: have you tried calling `rehash` to force MATLAB to detect changes in M-files? btw I'm not sure why you are using scripts but not functions..

Comment: ok I just noticed that you are using files on a network location. You might wanna read about file change notifications on Windows: `help changenotification`

Comment: @Amro rehash works like a charm, thank you. why scripts? My simulation consists of 50 m-files and around 80 different functions. It all starts with main, which calls the different functions for the simulation. Now I'm at a stage where I need to iterate certain stuff or do parameter sweep. One of those takes 2-7 hours of computational time. Then I wanted to use multiple computers at once. But as I'm to lazy to walk to every single one of them every time I need something, I wrote that polling script. This way I can modify files and put jobs in the queue and they will eventually get done

Comment: haha I see. Perhaps you should start using remote desktop or VNC, that way you can do all your work from one machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amro's solution with `rehash` works perfectly. Matlab detects changes in m-files even when it's already running a script!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to do what you want with a [`timer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer.html) object.

First create a main.m function to define and initialize your timer:

```
function main

% Create timer that calls the sub-function checkmfiles every 60 seconds
t = timer('TimerFcn', @checkmfiles, 'Period', 60, 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate');
start(t);

function checkmfiles(obj,events)
% Just a dummy function, you'll need to expand it to fit your needs
if exist(f1) == 2
    disp('''f1.m'' found.');
    eval('f1');
else
    disp('No file found.');
end
```

The example above assumes that `f1.m` doesn't exist initially. You can run `main.m` and then create an arbitrary `f1.m` (example assume that the function takes no inputs) afterwards that will be run by the timer callback. This method has the added benefit that it doesn't tie up your Matlab session while the timer runs.

Comment: Thanks, the benefit could really come in handy. It works now with the rehash command, but with using pause(..) I have an always busy matlab. That doesn't bother me tough as it doesnt use the CPU. Thanks tough.